# Sitecore ECM 2.1 Pausing Scheduled Emails

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-ecm

I'm sending an scheduled Email using Sitecore ECM 2.1 (3000 recipients) using the MTA service.

After a certain number of emails the message goes into a "paused" state. Is there anyway to resume the job once it's been paused?

Ian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open that email on SPEAK, and open the "Dispatch" tab, at the bottom of the form you should see the "resume" button. (It's at the same place as the Send and Schedule buttons)

Comment: I know your question has been answered already, but you should additionally look in the Sitecore logs after a send goes into a pause state in order to figure out why it's pausing.  You should be able to dispatch the campaign and not worry about it stopping.

Comment: When my email campaign fails to send and goes back to pause, it writes absolutely nothing to my Sitecore log. I click Resume, it goes right back to Pause with no indication anywhere as to why.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue and we had no idea why the campaigns were continually pausing. Today I found out why.
If there is a recipent in your csv file with a FullName or FirstName field that contains a '&' the sending process will pause when it tries to send to that user.

The solution to not have campaigns pause is to make sure the csv file does not contain any '&' characters.

hope this helps others.

Comment: Thanks for the info. There was an issue with the format of some recipients in my list also. Another thing was - there was some app pool recycles going on due to issues else where on the site- as the sending of emails is a sitecore job the job would pause.